# How to avoid multiple DB access for Sails.js policy and controller?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, policy

I put role checking in policy:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    var postId = req.param('postId');
    var userId = req.session.user.id;

    Post.findOne({id: postId})
        .exec( function (err, post) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }

            if (!post) {
                return res.notFound('Post not found');
            }

            if (post.author !== userId) {
                return res.forbidden('Not the author');
            }

            next();
        });
};
```

And in PostController, I need to fetch the post again (and possible populate some related data)

```
update: function (req, res) {
    var postId = req.param('postId');
    Post.findOne({id: postId}).populate('tags')
        .exec( function (err, post) {
        // Update the post here
```

I would like to know if there is a decent way to fetch the post record from DB with only one time?

Comment: I think you can put your post object under req object and retrieve it on your controller

Comment: If i put req.post = post in the exec(function(err, post) in policy, can I still populate it in PostController?

Comment: No you have to pouplate it on policy or retrieve on database on controller

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to have a solution. Since populating in policy means retrieving associated data on every request, it is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would make that policy to "mutilate" actual query, so that user condition is attached automatic to all requests. With that approach you can use blueprint actions to fetch that all.

I have done this myself, you can look at the code https://github.com/tarlepp/Taskboard/blob/angular/backend%2Fapi%2Fservices%2FRightsGet.js#L460 there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I was reading the source code of your Taskboard directly downloaded from http://tarlepp.github.io/Taskboard/. But that seems to be a much older version.